# How to find intersection of multiple lists excluding empty ones?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have lists like

```
list1={1, 1, 2, 3}; list2={3, 1, 4}; list3={};
```

I want to find the intersection of all list. I tried the following way, but it's not working.

```
Intersection[Cases[{list1, list2,list3}, Except[{}]]]
```

I want output like this

```
{1, 3}
```

Fell free, if you want to edit my question.

Comment: If list3=={}, the intersection will be {} ....

Comment: Try `Intersection @@ Cases[...]` @belisarius I think subbu wants to exclude empty sets from the list of intersected sets.

Comment: also: `Intersection @@ DeleteCases[{list1, list2, list3}, {}]`

Comment: @IstvánZachar you are right,what you understood

Comment: @subbu `Cases`, like many functions, returns a single list. But `Intersection` wants a set of lists to compare. So your code wasn't 'reaching far enough' into the results of `Cases` to give you the answer you want. If you haven't seen it already, [Leonid's](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node53.html) book is worth reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a different way:

```
list1 = {1, 1, 2, 3}; list2 = {3, 1, 4}; list3 = {};
Intersection @@ DeleteCases[{list1, list2, list3}, {}]
```

Which gives:

```
{1,3}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
list1 = {1, 1, 2, 3}; list2 = {3, 1, 4}; list3 = {};
Intersection[Sequence @@ Cases[{list1, list2, list3}, Except[{}]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the elements existing in more than one list you could try:

```
list1 = {1, 1, 2, 3};

list2 = {3, 1, 4};

list3 = {4};
Union @@ Intersection @@@ Subsets[{list1, list2, list3}, {2}]

(* {1, 3, 4} *)
```

**edit** With an empty list3

```
list1 = {1, 1, 2, 3};
list2 = {3, 1, 4};
list3 = {};
Union @@ Intersection @@@ Subsets[{list1, list2, list3}, {2}]
(* {1,3} *)
```

Comment: sorry,my list3 is empty like `{}`

Comment: @subbu Try it with `list3 = {}` then

Comment: If I assign `list3={}`,I will get output is like `{}`.But I want output like `{1,3}`.indirectly I want to exclude empty sets from the list of intersects sets.

Comment: @subbu See edit

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 1, 2, 3};
b = {3, 1, 4};
c = {};
```

Since V 13.1 we have `DeleteElements` and `SymmetricDifference`

```
With[{x = Sequence[a, b, c]},
 DeleteElements[Union @ x, SymmetricDifference @ x]]
```

{1, 3}

Answer (score 1):

We can, also, use [**`UniqueElements`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UniqueElements.html) that came with **v13.1**

```
DeleteDuplicates[
 Flatten[{List /@ a, List /@ b, List /@ c} /. 
    Flatten[Thread[UniqueElements[{a, b, c}] -> #] & @@ {placeholder},
      2]] /. placeholder :> Nothing]
```

> `{1,3}`